# Paypal server side REST api demo doesnt work on production mode?

Tags: rest, paypal, server-side, production

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

The link is a demo for Paypal server side rest api.

Works pretty well in sandbox mode.

But if I click on the **top right corner to switch to production mode**.

I get this error?

[image]

This is happening to one of my site too.

Comment: Hi Allen, that's because Sandbox creds are built in the demo. Don't want to assume anything here but did you add your logic/params with your LIVE rest creds?

Comment: @GeekNinja, Yes I did.